# Try-Catch Retry 3 times using different node each time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a try catch within a stage and I want to retry it 3 times, each time using a different VM but I'm running into issues.

I have managed to make it try running on 3 different VMs however I am getting  No such file or directory on all VMs except on one.
When I try running the pipeline on only one agent it runs fine on all of them but the issue appears when I retry on using different nodes:

```
pipeline {
    agent{
        label 'linux'
    }
    environment {
            added my env variables
    }
    stages {
        stage('stagename') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def nodes = env.NODES_LINUX.split(',') as List //i have all my VM names saved as glob variables
                    def isFirstRun = true
                    def selectedAgent = env.NODE_NAME

                     
                    retry(3) {
                        if (isFirstRun){ 
                            isFirstRun = false
                        } else {
                        def random = new Random()
                        selectedAgent = nodes[random.nextInt(nodes.size())]
                        }
                       
                        try {
                            node(selectedAgent) {
                                
                                    sh """chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"""
                                    sh """path/filename.sh""

                                }
                            
                        } catch (err) {
                            nodes.remove(selectedAgent)
                            echo "Failed: ${err}"
                            throw err
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       }     
    }
}
```